# points at infinity, asymptotes and branch of a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have this problem:
Let $f(X,Y)= 1+X^4+X^3Y^2-XY^4+Y^4 \in k[X,Y]$

(a)which are the points at infinity of the curve C?

(b)which are the asymptotes of C?

(c) In which direction does C have a parabolic branch?

I know the points at infinity are [1:0:0],[0:1:0],[1:1:0], [1:-1:0].

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do now is calculate the tangent lines (*) to the projectivized curve at the points at infinity. Then, each of these lines different from the line at infinity is an asymptote of the (affine) curve. If at a point at infinity, the tangent line is the line at infinity itself, the direction on affine plane represented by this point at infinity is a parabolic branch of the curve.

(*) If your projective curve is given by the zero locus of a homogeneous polynomial $F$ and it is smooth at a point $p\in \mathbb{P}^2$, remember that the tangent line is given as the zero locus of the polynomial
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial X_0 }(p)X_0+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial X_0 }(p)X_1+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial X_0 }(p)X_2$$

Comment: and how I know the multiplicity of each point?